# Stripe subscriptions with a pricing matrix

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm working on a site that will sell pet food and wants people to be able to subscribe to receive monthly deliveries.

The pricing matrix looks like:

```
                INACTIVE  AVERAGE   ACTIVE
  4kg  - 14kg   $58.00    $64.00    $67.00
  15kg - 22kg   $69.00    $74.00    $79.00
  23kg - 45kg   $88.00    $95.00    $101.00
  46kg - 60kg   $96.00    $108.00   $116.00
```

So there's 12 possible different base subscription prices but they can also choose to include an add-on in three different amounts/prices which means there would be 36 different price variations.

The client wants to use Stripe for their payment processing and I'm not sure what's the best way to approach it. I've looked at tiered pricing and multiple plans, but not sure whether they fit with what we're trying to do.

Has anyone else used Stripe to do this sort of thing?